# JDBC and MySQL DATE off by one - how to correct

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

I'm trying to retrieve and handle a MySQL computed DATE value in JDBC code. Here's a small snippet:

```
    MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlDataSource();
    ds.setServerName("myservername");
    ds.setUser("myusernamne");
    ds.setPassword("******");
    ds.setDatabaseName("mydbname");
    ds.setUseJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift(true);
    ds.setUseLegacyDatetimeCode(false);
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement p = con.prepareStatement("select last_day('2014-01-15')");
    ResultSet rs = p.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    Date date = rs.getDate(1);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(df.format(date));
```

I would expect this to print `2014-01-31` but instead it prints `2014-01-30`. Why, and what can I do about it? The machine running my JVM is in the US Eastern locale and the database is in UTC, but I would have thought with the parameters I set it should still handle that correctly.

In case it matters I'm running MySQL 5.5 and mysql-connector-java version 5.1.16.

Comment: I get 2014-01-31 within MySQL Workbench.  What is your result directly executing the query?

Comment: Indeed I get 2014-01-31 directly as well (I'm using Sequel Pro just for variety). My question is not about MySQL in isolation but about MySQL and JDBC together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This forces the time to be UTC instead of relying on local time:

```
Calendar gmt = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
rs.getDate(1, gmt);
```

Your query I believe returns the first instance of the day on 2014-01-31 and therefore subtracting the several hours difference does put you on the day before.

Comment: I see. I would have thought DATE values - specifically, as opposed to TIME or DATETIME or TIMESTAMP - would be indifferent to time zones, but I guess not.